# Enforce using HTTP proxy globally

Tags: windows, winapi, proxy, wfp

We have a task here - to redirect all http traffic from all applications running on computers running Win7 and Win8 to some proxy. So the only thing comes to my mind is to use WFP callout driver to inspect outgoing packets and modify them accordingly. So question is this - is it the only way to enforce using HTTP proxy globally for all applications running on Windows computer?
thanks.

Comment: If you want to do this "globally" another approach is to do this on a "network level" i.e. use a so-called "transparent proxy" which is independent of the client-side configuration...

Comment: @Yahia Yes, it may look like easy solution but it will not work in case if user has a mobile device/laptop/netbook. So users go out to Starbuks around the corner or connect to internet using tethering on mobile phones. That's not really "enforcing".

Comment: WFP callout drivers are only possible for Vista and newer OS versions... for older OS version you would need to deal with NDIS/TDI and similar which is much harder... How secure must the solution be ? What are your risk-scenarios ?

Comment: @Yahia Yes, Vista and above is the requirement. The solution must be secure enough so standard user couldn't bypass it (there is nothing we can do to prevent Administrators from deleting drivers or disabling services).

Comment: In your question you wirte about Win2K too ?!?

Comment: @Yahia I just simplified requirements, removed W2K and Vista.